# Concurrency with Objectify in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, concurrency, objectify

I created a test web application to test persist-read-delete of `Entities`, I created a simple loop to persist an `Entity`, retrieve and modify it then delete it for 100 times.

At some interval of the loop there's no problem, however there are intervals that there is an error that `Entity` already exist and thus can't be persisted (*a custom exception handling I added*).

Also at some interval of the loop, the `Entity` can't be modified because it does not exist, and finally at some interval the `Entity` can't be deleted because it does not exist.

I understand that the loop may be so fast that the operation to the `Appengine` datastore is not yet complete. Thus causing, errors like `Entity does not exist`, when trying to access it or the delete operation is not yet finished so creating an Entity with the same `ID` can't be created yet and so forth.

However, I want to understand how to handle these kind of situation where concurrent operation is being done with a `Entity`.

Comment: This needs a lot more explanation... these errors don't make any sense without the context of what you are doing.  However, if I had to guess, it sounds like you are doing async operations and not completing them.

Comment: @stickfigure Consider the example of two threads trying to update a Entity, if those two threads accessed the Entity at about the same time, then update the Entity, say increment a value, then by theory there will be a missing increment after the save operation of any of the two threads

Comment: This is exactly why transactions were invented :-)

Comment: @stickfigure Yah, I just read it from Objectify code site, I actually implemented the DAOT class, which works now, I believe that the DAOT patterns is well tested too

Comment: @stickfigure However after reading the wiki and the code, it seems that it build upon the ConcurrentModificationException to ensure that its not persisting at the same time, however, how about when reading counter values, is there an exception when an application tries to read a key at the same time?

Comment: @stickfigure I mean, like for the traditional example, of two threads read the same key at the same time and increment it? I means the value that both threads have and will commit will be wrong. I can't see in the code that does solve this in the DAOT code?

Comment: A transaction will throw ConcurrentModificationException on commit if some other txn committed a change to the entity first.  So the slower one will fail.  The DAOT pattern (and the transact() method in Ofy4) will automatically repeat concurrency failures until the txn succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are doings something like the following:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    ent = My_Entity()    # create and save entity
    db.put(ent)
    ent = db.get(ent.key())   # get, modify and save the entity
    ent.property = 'foo'
    db.put(ent)
    ent.get(ent.key())  # get and delete the entity
    db.delete(my_ent)
```

with some error checking to make sure you have entities to delete, modify, and you are running into a bunch of errors about finding the entity to delete or modify. As you say, this is because the calls aren't guaranteed to be executed in order.

> However, I want to understand how to handle these kind of situation where concurrent operation is being done with a Entity.

You're best bet for this is to batch any modifications you are doing for an entity persisting. For example if you are going to be creating/saving/modifying/savings or modifying/saving/deleting where ever possible try to combine these steps (ie create/modify/save or modify/delete). Not only will this avoid the errors you're seeing but it will also cut down on your RPCs. Following this strategy the above loop would be reduced to...

```
prop = None
for i in range(0,100):
    prop = 'foo'
```

Put in other words, for anything that requires setting/deleting that quickly just use a local variable. That's GAE's answer for you. After you figure out all the quick stuff you can't persist that information in an entity.

Other than that there isn't much you can do. [Transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions) can help you if you need to make sure a bunch of entities are updated together but won't help if you're trying to multiple things to one entity at once.

EDIT: You could also look at the [pipelines API](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/).

Comment: Right, batch transaction would be suitable for create/modify/save, there's another issue I want to tackle, that is, when two threads try to update a Entity (let say a points value) at the same time, that means when both threads save, the value is not the expected value, say for a increment points function

Comment: As a work-around you could go with the method that Brett Slatkin suggests on his Google IO talk [Building high-throughput data pipelines with Google App Engine](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/high-throughput-data-pipelines-appengine.html) 33:00